# How to use two separate block tags on the same template

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to create a template for a blog landing page. Basically, I am trying to extend certain features from my base template, so I have two block tags that I want to appear at different parts of the page.  Here is the first block tag;

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% for politic in politics %}
<div class="post-entry-1 col-lg-4 box mx-1">
    <a href="single-post.html"><img src="{{politic.image.url}}" alt="" class="post_img"></a>
    <div class="post-meta">
        <span class="date">{{politic.category}}</span> 
        <span class="mx-1">&bullet;</span> 
        <span>{{politic.created_at}}</span>
    </div>
    <h2 class="mb-2"><a href="single-politic.html">{{politic.title}}</a></h2>
    <span class="author mb-3 d-block">Ole Pundit</span>
    <p class="mb-4 d-block">{{politic.body|truncatewords:75}}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

But once the number of blog posts uploaded (politics.count) reaches 4, I want the for loop in the first block tag to break. And the following block tag to be executed;

```
{% block sidepolitics %}
{% if politics.count > 4 %}
{% for politic in politics %}
    <div class="post-entry-1 border-bottom">
        <div class="post-meta">
            <span class="date">{{politic.category}}</span>
            <span class="mx-1">&bullet;</span> 
            <span>{{politic.created_at}}</span>
        </div>
        <h2 class="mb-2">
            <a href="single-post.html">{{politic.title}}

            </a>
        </h2>
        <span class="author mb-3 d-block">Ole Pundit</span>
    </div>
{% endfor %}   
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Meaning the maximum number of blogposts that should follow the first layout is four, and the rest should all follow the second layout.

Both blog tags are nested under the political.html file below

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% for politic in politics %}
<div class="post-entry-1 col-lg-4 box mx-1">
    <a href="single-post.html"><img src="{{politic.image.url}}" alt="" class="post_img"></a>
    <div class="post-meta">
        <span class="date">{{politic.category}}</span> 
        <span class="mx-1">&bullet;</span> 
        <span>{{politic.created_at}}</span>
    </div>
    <h2 class="mb-2"><a href="single-politic.html">{{politic.title}}</a></h2>
    <span class="author mb-3 d-block">Ole Pundit</span>
    <p class="mb-4 d-block">{{politic.body|truncatewords:75}}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
{% block sidepolitics %}
{% if politics.count > 4 %}
{% for politic in politics %}
    <div class="post-entry-1 border-bottom">
        <div class="post-meta">
            <span class="date">{{politic.category}}</span>
            <span class="mx-1">&bullet;</span> 
            <span>{{politic.created_at}}</span>
        </div>
        <h2 class="mb-2">
            <a href="single-post.html">{{politic.title}}

            </a>
        </h2>
        <span class="author mb-3 d-block">Ole Pundit</span>
    </div>
{% endfor %}   
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

And here is my base template **index.html;

```
 <div class="d-flex align-items-end">
          {% block content %}
          {% endblock %}
          </div>
        </div>
         
        <div class="col-md-3">
          {% block sidepolitics %}
          {% endblock %}
        </div>
```

**view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post, Politics
from django.views.generic import DetailView

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def allposts(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'allposts.html', {'posts':posts})

def political(request):
    politics = Politics.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'political.html', {'politics':politics})

def post(request, pk):
    posts = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'posts.html', {'posts':posts})
```

The problem is, for both for loops the application starts iterating from the very beginning. How can I make the first for loop to iterate only up to the fourth count, and the second for loop to pick up right where the first loop leaves off.

Comment: You have in two places following code `{% for politics in politics %}` - even if the first loop works, the second one, the inner/nested loop, will raise error or at least produce unexpected result. That said, it's unclear what the problem/your question is.

Comment: I have edited the code, added more files and restructured the question to make my problem more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstfully, if you want to count objects, you need to use `.count` in template:

```
{% if politics > 4 %}         # good for integers or similar
{% if politics.count > 4 %}   # good for querysets
```

Secondly, you need to understand standard pythonish `for loops` because `{% for politics in politics %}` just makes absolutely no sense. It works like this:

```
{% for politic in politics %}    # usually it's like this: {% for SINGULAR in PLURAL %}
```

otherwise you are overriding `politics` variable and it should not work, at least not good.

Second loop makes no sense at all, I guess you don't need it.

With that said and your edits, use `forloop.counter`. It returns `int` with the current loop round. Here's hint:

```
{% for item in item_list %}
    {{ forloop.counter }} # starting index 1
    {{ forloop.counter0 }} # starting index 0
{% endfor %}
```

Instead of `{% if politics.count > 4 %}` that now I understand you don't need, use above logic. In first loop:

```
{% for politic in politics %}
    {% if forloop.counter < 5 %}
        # whole first for loop here
    {% else %}
        # whole second for loop here
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Using singular is just a naming convention, otherwise I came to find out that it really doesn't affect how the function works.

Comment: Otherwise, I have employed your solution and edited the question to make my problem more understandable

Comment: It's not just convention. If you do `{% for politics in politics %}` then in another internal `for` loop `politics` is not going to be the same as in the previous loop. If you don't understand this, noone will really understand you or your question :)

Comment: Okay, let me edit it out, I see if there will be any positive results

Comment: I have made the changes. But the results are still pretty much the same

Comment: I've edited. You need to change condition logic and use `forloop.counter`.

Comment: Should be {% if forloop.counter < 5 %}. Which solves the logic part of my question. If you can make that change then I can accept your answer

Comment: @Felicity Right, my mistake. Glad could've help.